# route changes when validations fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I have a jobplacements model.When i create new jobplacement i am passing category as a param like this :

```
new_jobplacement_path(:category => params[:category])
```

so url looks like this :

```
http://localhost:3000/jobplacements/new?category=Corporate
```

but when validations fails url changes to :

```
http://localhost:3000/jobplacements
```

**why this happens?where params category gets lost?how can i pass this params category when validations fail?**

my create action code is :

```
def create
        @jobplacement = Jobplacement.new(params[:jobplacement])
        if @jobplacement.save
        redirect_to(jobplacement_url(@jobplacement.id,:category => @jobplacement.category), :notice => 'Job post was successfully created.') 
    else
        render :action => "new" 
    end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your route for `create` action is

```
PUT http://localhost:3000/jobplacements
```

When you validations fails, the page is not redirected, so the url is remained.

Anyway, this will not cause problems.

Comment: no this causes problem because i need to store category through params...and when validations fails since there is no params value category is stored as empty which i dont want..

Comment: @NJF So you need to change your create route, let it have category.

Answer (score 0):

solved it...
added :url => { :action => :create, :category => params[:category]} in form.html.haml:

```
= form_for(@jobplacement,:url => { :action => :create, :category => params[:category]},:validate => true, :html => { :class => "form grid_6", :id => "form" }) do |f|
```

now when validations fail my url changes to :

```
http://localhost:3000/jobplacements?category=Corporate
```